# viewDidAppear UI unfathomable delay

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a project created from Xcode 6.  In  the root view controller, the `viewDidAppear` experienced this weird delay.  In the code below, creation of button and background color changed are immediate if calling from `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.  But there will be a delay if calling from `viewDidAppear`.

If button was created from `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, the response is not immediate.

The addition arithmetic in `viewDidAppear` is immediate.

The current and main threads are 1.

In `AppDelegate`, there is nothing in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

There is nothing loading in the view controller's init.

Any suggestions?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self createButton];
     NSLog(@"%s  currentthread:%@ mainthread:%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[NSThread currentThread], [NSThread mainThread]);
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
//    [self createButton];
    NSLog(@"%s  currentthread:%@ mainthread:%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[NSThread currentThread], [NSThread mainThread]);
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%s  currentthread:%@ mainthread:%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[NSThread currentThread], [NSThread mainThread]);
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    int i = 2;
    int j = 4;
    int m = i + j;
    NSLog(@"%s i:%u j:%u m: %u", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, i,j, m);

//    [self createButton];
}
-(void)createButton
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget: self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 40);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

viewDidAppear: is called after the view appears, so if you are doing something like changing the cover of a view it will be perceptible. If you don't want to see a color change, set the color in one of the other earlier lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that the Google's admob library created this problem.  I am using version 6.4.x.  Note that as I stated in my question, nothing loading in either AppDelegate or the view controller.  And none of admob classes were being used yet at that stage.

This problem only showed up in iOS 9.